# Arduino + E-Health Patient Position Sensor

Tags: position, arduino, accelerometer, sensors

I have been trying to read the analog output of the position sensor from the E-health sensor shield but to no avail. Does anyone have solutions for the code? Or is the sensor already been hard coded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to connect the external [Patient Position Sensor](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/patient-position-sensor-accelerometer-ehealth-medical) (Accelerometer).
A working example code can be found [here](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/ehealth-biometric-sensor-platform-arduino-raspberry-pi-medical)

EDIT: There are also the [eHealth sensor platform schematics](http://skin.cdn-libelium.com/frontend/default/cooking/images/catalog/documentation/e_health_v2/e-Health_v2.0.pdf) available, if you are interested further circuit details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the schematics, it will be a great help in the future. Yes i had visited the cooking hacks website. However it gives only example codes that display the 5 different positions. Is there any way the serial monitor can display the analog value for me to calibrate for a more precise result?

Comment: You can modify the function `_uint8_t eHealthClass::getBodyPosition(void)` in the cooking-hacks eHealth library file (eHealth.cpp, line 399, V.2.0). There are the raw analog signals, so that you can easily implement your own calibration and processing routine.